# jQuery on submit, output "r.fn.init {}"

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, init

Let's say we have this event:

```
$('form.ajax-form').on('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this));
});
```

This event is dispatching only when I submit the form, right? so it doesn't have to be nested in document ready event. When I submit my form, I get this output:

```
r.fn.init {}
```

I'm assuming it has to do something with jQuery initiating, but who is it related to my code? what am I missing here? It didn't happen to me in previous versions..

**Edit 1** - I'm expecting to see the HTML of the element.

Comment: Your code seems fine - and the output looks correct as you're logging the jQuery object directly. What were you expecting to see?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm probably doing something wrong on deprecated, because I was expecting to get the HTML object like I was always getting.

Comment: @Juhana Thank you. Changing `$(this)` to `$(e.currentTarget)` solved my issue.